# Scrapy Not Crawling Any Pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm crawling the site https://oa.mo.gov/personnel/classification-specifications/all. I need to get to each position page and then extract some information. I figure I could do this with a LinkExtractor or by finding all the URLs with xPath, which is what I'm attempting below. The spider doesn't show any errors, but also doesn't crawl any pages:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from StateOfMoJDs.items import StateOfMoJDs

class StateOfMoJDs(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'StateOfMoJDs'
    allowed_domains = ['oa.mo.gov']
    start_urls = ['https://oa.mo.gov/personnel/classification-specifications/all']

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath('//span[@class="field-content"]/a/@href').extract():
            url2 = 'https://oa.mo.gov' + url
            scrapy.Request(url2, callback=self.parse_job)


    def parse_job(self, response):
        item = StateOfMoJDs()
        item["url"] = response.url
        item["jobtitle"] = response.xpath('//span[@class="page-title"]/text()').extract()
        item["salaryrange"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="class-spec-compact"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/text()').extract()
        item["classnumber"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="class-spec-compact"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div//text()').extract()
        item["paygrade"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="class-spec-compact"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div//text()').extract()
        item["definition"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="class-spec-compact"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/p//text()').extract()
        item["jobduties"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="class-spec-compact"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div//text()').extract()
        item["basicqual"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="class-spec-compact"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div//text()').extract()
        item["specialqual"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="class-spec-compact"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div//text()').extract()
        item["keyskills"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="class-spec-compact"]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div//text()').extract()
        yield item
```

When using scrapy shell, `response.xpath('//span[@class="field-content"]/a/@href').extract()` yields a comma-separated list of relative URLs:

```
['/personnel/classification-specifications/3005', '/personnel/classification-specifications/3006', '/personnel/classification-specifications/3007', ...]
```

Comment: Does it at least crawl the entry in `start_urls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `parse()` method you need to `yield` your requests:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url2, callback=self.parse_job)
```